Set card half over one another layout
I have been trying setting card in jet compose android in a way it place half over one layout and another half over other layout as shown in below pics
I have tried following code so far
@Composable
fun HomeUI(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
Column {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .background(colorResource(id = R.color.colorPrimary))
            .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 150.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Sign Up",
            color = colorResource(id = R.color.white),
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        )
        Row(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomStart)) {
            for (i in 1..3) {
                Card(
                    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant
                    ),
                ) {
                    Column {
                        Image(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                                .padding(5.dp),
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.sedan),
                            contentDescription = "City Rides",
                        )
                        Text(
                            text = "City Rides",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(16.dp)
                                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        )
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
But not able to achieved the same. Some suggestions please !
This is my result


Can you share the result achieved by your code?

You can remove Row composable from Box scope and place it below it i.e., directly inside Column scope and apply negative Y-Offset:
@Composable
fun HomeUI(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column {
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .background(colorResource(id = R.color.black))
                .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 150.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Sign Up",
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.white),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            )
        }
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().offset(y = -(60.dp)),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            for (i in 1..3) {
                Card(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(8.dp)
                        .size(100.dp),
                    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant
                    ),
                ) {
                    Column {
                        Image(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                                .padding(5.dp),
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_battery_50),
                            contentDescription = "City Rides",
                        )
                        Text(
                            text = "City Rides",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(16.dp)
                                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        )
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Sample Output:


It will not work on different screen sizes and resolutions

You can update y offset based on screen size(local configuration)

When you align Row inside a Box with Bottom alignment setting offset as half of the Row height would push it to be centered in 2 Layouts. But since taking height of Row creates one frame delay you might use a workaround to show whole layout for that case with drawWithContent.
@Preview
@Composable
fun LayoutSample() {

    var offsetY by remember {
        mutableIntStateOf(-1)
    }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .drawWithContent {
                if (offsetY >= 0) {
                    drawContent()
                }
            }
    ) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 150.dp)
                .background(Color.Red),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomStart
        ) {

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .onPlaced {
                        if (offsetY < 0) {
                            offsetY = it.size.height / 2
                        }
                    }
                    .offset {
                        IntOffset(0, offsetY.coerceAtLeast(0))
                    }
                    .height(Random.nextInt(50, 100).dp)
            ) {

                for (i in 1..3) {
                    Card(
                        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                            containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceContainer
                        ),
                    ) {
                        Column(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight().aspectRatio(1f)
                        ) {
                            Image(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .width(200.dp)
                                    .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                                    .padding(5.dp),
                                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.landscape1),
                                contentDescription = "City Rides",
                            )
                            Text(
                                text = "City Rides",
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .padding(16.dp)
                                    .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                            )
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        }

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f).background(Color.White)
        )
    }
}

More robust approach would be creating Layout with 3 contents and positioning center layout below top layout minus half of the center layout
